# Как сделать ссылку при нажатии на которую пользователя перемещало в нужное поле на странице?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форум с возможностью хайда.

Если юзер не залогинен, то он видет [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать ссылку на фразе "logged in users" которая перемещала пользователя в сайдбар в поле логин/пароль на этой же странице, без переходов на какие-либо другие страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это реализовать? Заранее благодарю за помощь :)

Comment: как вариант ```<label for="idInputUsername">logged in users</label>```

Comment: отличный вариант, благодарю вас от всей души :)

Comment: Создать `div` дать ему `position: fixed` и спрятать за экран пользователя, logged in users сделать отдельным элементом, на него повесить отдельный клик и на клик выводить поле регистрации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для автоматической прокрутки страницы в то место, где находится элемент, который должен стать в поле видимости прокрутки, используют так называемые якоря:

```html
<a href="#top">В другое место документа</a>
 ... 
 ... 
 ... 
<a name="top">Это место</a>
```

Взято от сюда: [якоря](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya)